# DataTables Responsive: Remove row when columns are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to create grid.

It's a great tool, but I have a problem with which occurs when the grid columns are hidden for example on mobile or other small devices where there is not enough room to display all columns.

**Problem:**

Removing grid row when columns are hidden. When are columns are showing it works just fine.

**Table code:**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm removeRow">Remove this row</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm removeRow">Remove this row</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
  });
});

$(".removeRow").click(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
});
```

I am attaching link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kid_plama/a4w0gv2q/). You can clearly see it works when columns are shown, and it breaks when columns are hidden.

I wonder if anyone else came across similar issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by "breaks" in the fiddle when pressing remove on both rows it works as expected.

Comment: Nvm i see what you mean. The reason why is that the structure of the html changes when the responsiveness kicks in.

Comment: Also when it is responsive your remove button is added to the dom after the plus icon is pressed. so there is no event attached to it. so you have two problems. The remove button is no longer a child of the tr you want to remove and there is no event attached to it.

Comment: Maybe you can try `$(document).on("click",".removeRow",function() {. EDIT: even this will be necessary because the child element is dynamically added you need to implement an other additional method which has to respond to this changes

Comment: Thank you for tips,  I have managed to fix the issue. I will post answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue. I decided to post it in case anyone else has similar problem.

This wasn't working because HTML structure changes when columns are collapsing. To fix this I added extra check, to verify if columns are collapsed or not.

**Amended code:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeRow", function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();  
  var row;

  console.log($(this).closest('table'));
  if($(this).closest('table').hasClass("collapsed")) {
    var child = $(this).parents("tr.child");
    row = $(child).prevAll(".parent");
  } else {
    row = $(this).parents('tr');
  }

  table.row(row).remove().draw();

});
```

It's now working fine.

Here is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kid_plama/zrpL9ptr/1/).